# Rendering GPX track data onto video?

Tags: gpx, software-recommendations, tracklog

I have two geeky passions while driving: recording GPX data to upload to OSM as well as recording on board videos like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rSsHEy1JQc). Since these kind of videos are sort of boring for others to watch I was wondering if maybe there's an application out there to convert the track data into a video which I could then overlay over my original recording showing real time stuff like time of day, speed, elevation, etc. Basically a HUD. If there was a way to show part of the map I'm driving through that would be dreamy.

Do you know of such a piece of software?

Comment: This isn't an advert, just a satisfied user's report. If you have an Android device and a OBD II dongle that plugs into modern cars (>= 2001 for petrol, >= 2004 for diesels, in Europe), you can use Android Torque (http://torque-bhp.com/) to record tracks, video, and all the diagnostics your car emits.

Comment: Acting as a _fruity logo fanboy_ I will note there are [similar apps for iOs](http://devtoaster.com/products/rev/index.html). But I think the question was how you can process existing video (from onboard camera) with GPX data to obtain videos with HUD and map data.

Comment: Perhaps just make a mashup of google maps and youtube?

Comment: @MatthewSnape: like [this](http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2009/04/you-tube-and-google-earth.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ActionCam](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://gis4all.ru/soft/action-cam-gps-video-player/) is a nice visualization tool. You can used this and a desktop video recording tool as a workaround.

I also came across [MPGHead Video Data](http://www.mpghead.com/VideoDataMerger/) Merger but it only works with TrackVision CSV data. Oh, and there's [TrackVision](http://www.trackvision.net/products.shtml) ;) And [DashWare](http://www.dashware.net/) which gets lots of praise online and can do [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8h-S-pDVsw).

There are also several online sharing services which will let you combine video and GPS data, such as:

- [vidmap.de](http://www.vidmap.de/video/324/en/Video-of-Niagara-Falls-USA)
- [attackpoint.org](http://attackpoint.org/sessiondata.jsp?sessionid=1673057&vtype=vimeo&vid=18254718&voffset=1)

Comment: Thank you for your excellent response. DashWare seems to hit the sweetspot for me. Now I'm pondering a purchase...

Comment: As the author of the MPGHead Video Data Merger, I appreciate the traffic.  Although I've not worked on the app in a long (long) time, the concept of my tool still works for what OP is asking... you'd just need to understand the GPX format (which is easy: http://weblogs.asp.net/jimjackson/archive/2009/03/10/using-linq-to-xml-with-c-to-read-gpx-files.aspx) and use that vs. my data source.

Answer (score 2):

`gpsbabel` (open source) could be used to [produce](https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.5.4/fmt_subrip.html) `.srt` subtitles for your video from `.gpx` (or any other supported) track file. Then you can play video with subtitles to get HUD.

Most basic example with default SRT string format:

```
$ gpsbabel -i gpx -f trip.gpx -o subrip -F video.srt
```

[Synthesize speed](https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.5.4/filter_track.html#fmt_track_o_speed) if missing (`--.- km/h`) in the 'trip.gpx'.

```
$ gpsbabel -i gpx -f trip.gpx -x track,speed -o subrip -F video.srt
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar challenge. After my 9 month Melbourne to London trip I had terabytes of GPS tracks, dashcam, drone and other handheld video footage that I wanted to compile into entertaining video. After spending months of experimenting with different tools I have come to the conclusion:

- all GPS data from drone and dashcam was converted to KML.
- Google Mymaps, Google Earth and QGIS for static images of the KML tracks on maps and satellite view.
- Google Earth Studio to produce short video clips, with the KML track as overlays.
- The GPS tracks were imported (KML) as layers in QGIS. Exported from QGIS as SVG's, these SVG's were imported into Adobe Illustrator and from there imported in Adobe After Effects. In After Effects you can use the paths from the GPS tracks to fly along the track over a map or earth view.
- Adobe After Effects to compile a visual representation of data like kms driven and fuel consumed with video footage (dashcam, drone, hand, footage from google Earth Studio, QGIS atlas frames, handrecorded footage,...).
- If you need more than a minute or so of video, you'll probably need to compile shorter clips into a longer video using Adobe Premiere Pro.

Comment: All answers are welcome, even 8 years later. :) Can you share the end result?

Answer (score 2):

I have made this web app if you want to try: https://www.geofoobar.com. It is a very simple GPS track overlay rendering tool. It will render video frames as numbered png files, which you can then use in your video editor to overlay your footage.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the video generation tool on mapstovideo.com might be useful. It accepts a gpx file and photos to generate a map video with background music. If you want to overlay this on your video ffmpeg would be the tool to look at.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).