# Video UAV Tracker for QGIS (2.14)?

Tags: qgis, tracklog, video

I would like to view videos and my position on the videos' gpx tracks simultaneously and I would like to do it in QGIS. I know that there is a plugin for this but it was made for an earlier version of QGIS and doesn't work for me. By the way, exactly that is what I am looking for. Right now I'm using 2.14. 
Are there solutions for this case?

(I used Garmin's VIRB camera)

Comment: seems like it lost compatibility for me too. You could try snagging an older version of qgis. does the virb save a gpx file or can you extract a gpx from the file it saves?

Comment: It saves a gpx file. I have thought about returning to an older version but I really don't want to as I use QGIS on a daily basis and 2.14 is better for that. 

(by the way, I found an app called Dashware which seems pretty cool)

Comment: check out routeshoot as well. I think the main benefit of the qgis plugin is the ability to add your own map underneath, to not rely on what level of detail google has for your area.

Comment: also check out this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21588/rendering-gpx-track-data-into-video?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This works with the .gpx file
I got the answer from sourceforge.net

If you want to use Video UAV Tracker you need a video and a gpx file ( 1 point per second) in sync and with the same lenght.
To do that you can do like this:

1. When you start the video, focus on a GPS time. (Attention, if you are focusing on a NMEA string the time string could be an UTC time, that 
   diff from GPS time by 16 seconds now (it change year after year)
2. Calculate the start time and the end time of the video on the GPS time.
3. Cut the video to fit the .gpx file with a video editor
4. Set the same name for video and gpx file and put theme in the same folder. (if the video name is "MOVIETEST.MP4" the gpx file will be "MOVIETEST.MP4.gpx" )
5. When you start the Plugin, after pushing the Open button, you have to select the video file, not the gpx one.